# Moment.js (Custom) Date Format to Rails Date Format

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, momentjs

I was asking myself if there is an easy way to convert `Moment.js` (Javascript) (custom) time formats to `Ruby/Rails` DateTime formats, which also includes custom formats.

**Example (Javascript Chrome Console):**

```
var raw_string = "2017-02-28T01:28:27Z"

var my_custom_date_format = "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ"

var parsed_string = moment(raw_string, my_custom_date_format)

console.log(parsed_string._f) # returns my_custom_date_format
```

I now want to send `my_custom_date_format` to `Ruby/Rails` and parse using:

**IRB Console (Ruby):**

```
require 'time'

time1 = Date.strptime("2017-02-28T01:28:27Z", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ") *
```

*✘ This would break because of another syntax.

```
time1 = Date.strptime("2017-02-28T01:28:27Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") **
```

** ✔This works, but I need a automatic converter of all possible js date formats to `Ruby`.

I was thinking of solving this issue maybe with `RegEx`, if possible or are there libraries able to convert this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Because my customers have export functionalities in their system and have different kind of time formats. How many permutations are there Y m d H M s TZ Offset (.) (-) ?

Comment: Looks interesting, can you provide more example of input and expected output and the syntax you mentioned will break things?